# Apply some Prisma migrations only on certain environments

Tags: sql, postgresql, testing, integration-testing, prisma

I have two sets of environments I'd like to run checks differently on.

On the production database, there's a table that is append-only; a trigger prohibits deletes and updates.

However, for the sake of testing, on the test database I'd like to run deletes.

What would be the best practice for this, given I use Prisma migrations?

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting use case. One possible workaround is keeping a separate SQL file that disables/ deletes the trigger and executing it on your test database using `prisma db execute` after running `prisma migrate deploy`. I.e:

```bash
prisma db execute ./<path-to-file>/delete-trigger.sql
```

Feel free to refer to the [`prisma db execute`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/command-reference#db-execute) CLI reference for further details. Let me know how it goes and don't hesitate to reach out if you run into any issue. :)